# Создать новый html-файл

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gulp

Мне нужно создавать новый `HTML-файл` и в его `document.html.innerHTML` помещать значение переменной `newHTML`. Можно ли сделать такое с помощью "чистого" Javascript или может есть какие-нибудь `node js` или `gulp` библиотеки?

```
let newHTML = parse();

function createNewHTML(htmlCode) {
    // some text
}

createNewHTML(newHTML);
```

Comment: может просто файл создать, и в него newHTML текстом

Comment: эта функция будет вызвана не единожды и каждый раз должен создаваться новый файл

Comment: @АлексейШиманович, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2496710/9464680